# Python regular expression on scrapy response or item that can remove everything between two strings

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm scraping a site and the element I want doesn't have a text value.

In order to get the value I'm after in some shape or form I need 
extract the value between `arrowTo(foo)-`

I want to remove everything and leave foo

The value I'm extracting is the whole div using this

```
financials['arrow_value']  = response.xpath("//div[@class='dot-aqQgEO_r']/following-sibling::div[1]").extract_first()
```

How do I elegantly do this with scrapy or regex?

```
[
{"arrow_value": "<div class=\"arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToBuy-1R7d8UMJ arrowBuyShudder-3GMCnG5u\"> 
<div class=\"arrowMain-4Z6WqtKf\"></div><div class=\"arrowHidden-chDYo-JT\"></div></div>"} 

{"arrow_value": "<div class=\"arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToBuy-1R7d8UMJ arrowBuyShudder-3GMCnG5u\"> 
<div class=\"arrowMain-4Z6WqtKf\"></div><div class=\"arrowHidden-chDYo-JT\"></div></div>"} 

{"arrow_value": "<div class=\"arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToSell-2niuhIkD arrowSellShudder- 
mudaBhtR\"><div class=\"arrowMain-4Z6WqtKf\"></div><div class=\"arrowHidden-chDYo-JT\"</div> 
</div>"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex, `\w+` captures any word character till `-` is reached.

```
arrow_value = "<div class=\"arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToBuy-1R7d8UMJ arrowBuyShudder-3GMCnG5u\">" \
              "<div class=\"arrowMain-4Z6WqtKf\"></div><div class=\"arrowHidden-chDYo-JT\"></div></div>"

print(re.findall("arrowTo(\w+)-", arrow_value))
```

outputs,

```
['Buy']
```

Comment: @sunhanth is there any way I can avoid a loop? I've tried this and I'm not getting any regex applied.

Comment: @tomoc4, yes this is the regex ``arrowTo(\w+)-`` that will extract the details & assuming ```response.xpath``` returns a string u can directly pass to ```findall``` to extract the values.

Comment: yes it does make sense. I'll have to take a look when I wake in the morning. it's really late where I'm based and scrapy is timing out with "bad gateway" and behaving weird. This way happening before I posted the question. I'll comment and best answer in a few hours time:)